# Test a function passed as argument to another function in Jasmine

Tags: jasmine

I am getting below error(which is OK!) when called `tohaveBeenCalledWith`:

```
spy showError to have been called with [ '33' ] but actual calls were [ Function, 403 ]
```

Is there any way I can test **Function** that the function called with?

Assuming that the argument **Function is testFun**, How can I test  if $window.location.href hascorrect value applied

```
function testFun(errorStatus) {
            switch (errorStatus) {
                case 401:
                    $window.location.href = url1;
                    break;
                case 403:
                    $window.location.href = url2;
                    break;             
                default:
                    console.log('Something went wrong');

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can do that using [`jasmine.any`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Matching_Anything_with_<code>jasmine.any</code>)

Quoting the documentation example:

```
expect(foo).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Number), jasmine.any(Function));
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply.
Assuming that the argument Function is testFun, How can I test  if $window.location.href hascorrect value applied
`code`
function testFun(errorStatus) {
            switch (errorStatus) {
                case 401:
                    $window.location.href = url1;
                    break;
                case 403:
                    $window.location.href = url2;
                    break;             
                default:
                    console.log('Something went wrong');

            }
        }

Comment: @PravinVarma it's not readable here. Please update the question itself

Comment: @PravinVarma just put `jasmine.any(Function)` in param where you are getting that error. That should work

Comment: I have exposed the function to scope and tested it. Thanks

Comment: @PravinVarma glad it worked. Please upvote and accept answer if you found my efforts helpful.