# Jasmine - Test a method which has a function as Parameter

Tags: angular, ionic2, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a method which has an Object and a Function as a parameter, expecting it to have been called with its Object and a Function, but even though I pass a function, it returns an error.

```
Expected spy openContactEdit to have been called with [ Object({ ... }),
  Function ] but actual calls were [ Object({ ... }), Function ].
```

This is how my code looks like:

**contact-edit.test.ts**

```
class ModalControllerMock {
  static create(page: any, data?: any) {
    return new ModalMock;
  }
}

class ModalServiceMock {
  openContactEdit(contact: any, onDismiss: (data) => any): any {
    let modal = ModalControllerMock.create('EditContactPage', {
      contact: contact
    })

    modal.present();

    let data: any;

    onDismiss(data);
  }
}

it('should open edit contact page', () => {
  const contact = {
    "username": "callain0",
    "name": "Cordelia Allain"
  }
  spyOn(modalService, 'openContactEdit').and.callThrough();

  comp.editContact(contact)

  expect(modalService.openContactEdit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(contact, () => { });
});
```

**modal-service.ts**

```
openContactEdit(contact: any, onDismiss: (data) => any) {
  let modal = this.modalCtrl.create('EditContactPage', {
    contact: contact
  })

  modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
    onDismiss(data);
  })

  modal.present();
}
```

Comment: An anonymous arrow function isn't going to evaluate equal to the function you're actually calling it with. If you don't care about what the function is, try [`jasmine.any`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Matching_Anything_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.any%3C/code%3E).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your `() => {}` with `jasmine.any(Function)` and you'll be set if you don't care about the specific function. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376256/test-a-function-passed-as-argument-to-another-function-in-jasmine).